# How do I change references to an AWS Lambda Layer when it gets uploaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm using an AWS Lambda layer to keep some node_modules as well as some of my own helper functions, which I've stored in a folder called `helpers`. From AWS documentation I see that to reference my helpers which are in the layer I have to do

```
require('/opt/layer/helpers/foo.js');
```

However currently in my code I have it as

```
require('./helpers/foo.js');
```

and I want to keep it this way so that I am able to run locally. Is there a way to keep the second path and only change it to the first one when I upload the code (I'm using `aws lambda update-function-code` from CLI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if you are running on Lambda, then require the relevant code path. For example:

```
const isLambda = !!process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT;

const foo = require(isLambda ? '/opt/layer/helpers/foo.js' : './helpers/foo.js');
```

You could automate this replacement across your codebase using `sed` or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I have quite a few lambda functions... is there a way that doesn't require me to edit each file?

Comment: Instead of directly using the awscli to update the Lambda, call a script that modifies your source code, then updates the Lambda using awscli, then finally undoes the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the batch script I ended up writing (for Windows). In my case the enclosing folder for all my helpers was called /layer/helpers.

```
:: This batch file redeploys an existing lambda function
echo off
echo WARNING: this will delete any index.js or index.zip you have in the current directory!
pause
set /p toDeploy=Enter lambda name (without the .js): 
powershell -Command "(gc %toDeploy%.js) -replace './helpers', '/opt/layer/helpers' | Out-File -encoding ASCII index.js"
powershell "Compress-Archive index.js index.zip"
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name %toDeploy% --zip-file fileb://index.zip
del index.js
del index.zip
```